# Using round function in python

Tags: python

I want to round my answers to four decimal places after calculations but before they are stored in the 'probs' dictionary. I have tried using the 'round' function in the print (probs) statement and also in the line above but the error is that this dict does not allow the **round** method.

```py
HPRD_db = sequence.readFastaFile('HPRD.fa', sequence.Protein_Alphabet)
# Your code to construct HPRD background below
counts = {'A':0,'C':0,'D':0,'E':0,'F':0,'G':0,'H':0,'I':0,'K':0,'L':0,'M':0,'N':0,'P':0,'Q':0,'R':0,'S':0,'T':0,'V':0,'W':0,'Y':0}
total = 0
for seq in HPRD_db:
    for nt in seq.alphabet:
        counts[nt] += seq.count(nt)

for nt in counts:
    total += counts[nt]


probs = {}

for nt in counts:
    probs[nt] = counts[nt] / float(total)
print(probs)
```

The output of the probs dictionary is:

```py
{'A': 0.06984578386497987, 'C': 0.023122616793955175, 'D': 0.04814769879543413, 'E': 0.07064443899675797, 'F': 0.03724399454951442, 'G': 0.06608386984000873, 'H': 0.026116296117699497, 'I': 0.04427741198662404, 'K': 0.05762853493424018, 'L': 0.09913638061282196, 'M': 0.02165875240348138, 'N': 0.0366184744463036, 'P': 0.06165068623619301, 'Q': 0.04719159416959176, 'R': 0.05605356467437009, 'S': 0.08174647019029524, 'T': 0.052927746605418616, 'V': 0.060404874541272385, 'W': 0.012089388058578817, 'Y': 0.02741142218245913}
```

Comment: `"{0:.2f}".format(a)`

Comment: @TheLazyScripter where would you insert this line? Into print(probs)?

Comment: `print "{0:.2f}".format(probs)` will print the string representation of the float to the specified precision. Change `.2f` to whatever precision is necessary.

Comment: @TheLazyScripter I am getting the error msg: TypeError: unsupported format string passed to dict.__format__

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the round() function like this:

```
for nt in counts:
    probs[nt] = round(counts[nt] / float(total), 4)
print(probs)
```